# create-react-app: using --scripts-version and --typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I learn to use React with Typescript. In the [manual](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter#typescript-react-starter) I see it uses the `--scripts-version` parameter for create new application:

`create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts`

Also I see `create-react-app` has the `--typescript` option. So, I can write this:

`create-react-app my-app --typescript`

What is difference of these approaches of React-based application creating? Does it make sense to specify both of these parameters? I.e.

`create-react-app my-app --typescript --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to use both:

```
create-react-app my-app --typescript --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
```

`react-scripts-ts` was [deprecated](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript):

> create-react-app now supports typescript natively - read the guide for adding typescript to existing projects.

As `create-react-app` [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript) states,

> To start a new Create React App project with TypeScript, you can run:
>
> ```
> npx create-react-app my-app --typescript
>
> # or
>
> yarn create-react-app my-app --typescript
> ```

The difference is that `react-scripts-ts` uses TypeScript instead of Babel, while `create-react-app` uses Babel with TypeScript plugin. This leads to some [limitations](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript):

> Does not support namespaces. Workaround: Move to using file exports,
>   or migrate to using the module { } syntax instead.
>
> Does not support const enums because those require type information to
>   compile. Workaround: Remove the const, which makes it available at
>   runtime.
>
> Does not support export = and import =, because those cannot be
>   compiled to ES.next. Workaround: Convert to using export default and
>   export const, and import x, {y} from "z".